# FreeBSD - Unable to install GNOME Desktop Environment

Tags: gnome, freebsd

I'm unable to install GNOME Desktop Environment on FreeBSD-10 w/ `pkgng`. I'm following FreeBSD's handbook - [6.7. Desktop Environments](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/x11-wm.html):

```
root@:~ # pkg install gnome2
Updating repository catalogue
pkg: No packages matching 'gnome2' available in the repositories
root@:~ # uname -a
FreeBSD  10.0-RELEASE FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE #0 r260789: Thu Jan 16 22:34:59 UTC 2014     root@snap.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
root@:~ #
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm following handbook exactly step-by-step! `pkgng` itself is working fine, I *AM* able to install other binary packages (http://pastebin.com/zfvUztUK).

---

please, do *NOT* just downvote, use comment section as well to explain what's actually "wrong" (as without your input i cannot improve myself), also if the reason you're down-vote is because I'm not using `/usr/ports`, well then you need to realize that `pkgng` is yet another way to get around in FreeBSD.

Comment: Why don't you build it from the ports tree? Also, why would you *want* gnome on freebsd?

Answer (score 3):

If you do intend on installing this with the ports tree:

```
cd /usr/ports/x11/gnome2
make install clean
```

If you insist on using pkgng you need to enable it using the following instructions if you have not done so:

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/pkgng-intro.html

You may also need to modify pkgng to point at the freebsd repo

my /usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/FreeBSD.conf:

```
FreeBSD: {
    url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest"
    Mirror_type: "srv",
    enabled: yes
 }
```

EDIT: It appears that after updating my pkgng repo catalog the full gnome2 desktop pkg is no longer there. Your other options are to build from the ports tree as is suggested above, build your own pkg, or install gnome2-lite and then install additional packages until you are closer to gnome2 full.

Comment: I am able to use `pkgng` to install other packages (just not gnome2) see following -> http://pastebin.com/zfvUztUK

Comment: Very strange! I searched gnome2 and found it but needed to update pkgng. I updated pkgng and the pkg list then searched again. Now there is only gnome2-lite. What is the output of pkg search gnome2?

Comment: output: http://pastebin.com/gdA8BdYQ